# Dynamically populate select dropdown from parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I populate a select dropdown in my view to be the value of a certain parameter:

`http://localhost:3000/?group_size=6` - where I want the dropdown selects to be 1-6 as so:

```
<select name="group_size">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="6">Six</option>
</select>
```

Best would be to display the text for the number, but at least to create the text fields without names would be needed. This is Ruby 2.3 Rails 4.2. What do I need to write in the view and/or controller to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

In your view you could do something like...

```
<select name="group_size">
  <% (1..params[:group_size]).each_with_index do |i| %>
    <option value="<%= i %>"><%= i %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

This creates a [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) between 1 and whatever group size is passed. See the Ruby documentation for `each_with_index` [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index).

Note: This will break if no `group_size` is provided. I'll leave it to you to guard against nil. :)